# Convert to Json request from magento SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I need to convert the response from magento SOAP API to json, How to achieve this, Here is the code

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); 
$result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: You can get help here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send json data back from magento end you need to overwrite each function in magento API

For Example catalogProductList() method

Copy file

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api.php

To

> app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api.php

And modify below function

```
public function items($filters = null, $store = null)
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    /** @var $apiHelper Mage_Api_Helper_Data */
    $apiHelper = Mage::helper('api');
    $filters = $apiHelper->parseFilters($filters, $this->_filtersMap);
    try {
        foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
    $result = array();
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $result[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
            'website_ids'  => $product->getWebsiteIds()
        );
    }
    return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..  I have added the code but no data is fetched the output i am getting is array(0) { }

Comment: You have products in your shop?

Comment: yes.. The output of the default code is array(1429) { [0]=>

Comment: Copy original function items () from core file and just replace return statement

Comment: Getting same output

Comment: now you need to tack code. is actually calling your new function ?

Comment: Print $collection->getSelect(); in both case i.e (old code /new code) and check what is difference ?

Comment: @vellaidurai any updates  for this ?

Comment: @MineshPatel can i get help regard object to xml issue? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/250148/57334

Answer (score 0):

To decode JSON into an array you can use the following code:

```
$array = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($result);
```

To encode an array into JSON you can use the following code:

```
$json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result);
```